# Consulta SQL server 2000 para facturación

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito generar una consulta **`sql`** que me devuelva, los datos desde la tabla facturas (de la última factura), juntamente con el detalle de la misma, de la tabla `detalle_de_facturas`, lo que he hecho es

```
SELECT facturas.*, detalle_de_facturas.*
FROM (...)
GRUOP BY (...agrupo todos los campos a mostrar)
...y por ultimo que es mi duda...
HAVING (MAX(facturas.IDFACTURA)=detalle_de_faturas.IDFACTURA)
```

Básicamente quiero mostrar todo de la última factura, poniendo el `id` máximo, ya que es `Identity`.

Answer (score 3):

No es necesario hacerlo de esa forma, agrupando cada columna. Puedes obtener la última factura así:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.facturas f
INNER JOIN dbo.detalle_de_facturas df
   ON f.IDFACTURA = df.IDFACTURA
WHERE f.IDFACTURA = (SELECT MAX(IDFACTURA) FROM dbo.facturas);
```

Comment: te re agradezco bro! de que apuro me sacaste! graciass!!! anduvo a la perfeccion!!!

Comment: @RoberSonda No hay problema, me alegro que sirvió

Comment: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Lamak un grande!, ya estoy avanzando en mi proyecto, un alivio tengo!

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    dbo.facturas f
    INNER JOIN dbo.detalle_de_facturas df ON f.IDFACTURA = df.IDFACTURA
WHERE
    f.IDFACTURA = (SELECT TOP 1 FROM dbo.facturas ORDER BY IDFACTURA DESC)
```

Comment: Esto no es lo mismo. Porque si la última factura tiene 5 registros de detalles, tu consulta solo va a devolver uno de esos 5 registros, pero según, la pregunta, debería devolver *todos* los detalles de la última factura.

Comment: @Garrizano gracias por el aporte de todas maneras bro,  @ sstan gracias tambien por tu correccón y ayuda para resolver el problema planteado, desde ya muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Ahh eso sí @sstan, no me había percatado de eso. Creo que el TOP 1 era en lugar del MAX() de la solución que dio Lamark